# Script has random 'Operation Not Permitted' Error

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-18.04

**Premise**

I couldn't find a tool or script that would rename multiple files (100+) in the manner I needed it to. So I tried to write a Bash Script utilizing the 'mv' command.

**Problem**

The script does it's job and renames most of the files but then randomly outputs the 'Operation Not Permitted' error while renaming the files.

**Error Output**

*mv: cannot move 'filename.extension' to 'newFilename.extension': Operation not permitted*

**The Script**

```sh
a=1
for i in *.<extension>; do
  newName=$(printf "%03d <filename>.<extension>" "$a") #03 = Amount of 0 Padding you want to add
  sudo mv -i -- "$i" "$newName"
  let a=a+1
done
```

Thank You in advance for any possible help.

Comment: you don't really have `<extension>` (and others) in your code, do you? You should show your actual code, as it is often the little things that cause problems. Please update your Q with you "real" code ;-). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rarely a good idea to have sudo inside scripts. Instead, remove the sudo from the script and run the script itself with sudo:

```
sudo myscript.sh
```

That way, all commands within the script will be run with root privileges and you only need to give the password once when launching the script.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the advice. I'll change it now. Do you think it would stop the error though and why?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting sudo in the script remove it and run the script using sudo.

```
sudo script.sh
```

If that still doesn't work make sure your user id is in the sudoers file so you will have the necessary root privileges.